# How can I accurately calculate the number of characters in a string with special characters using PHP?

Tags: php

I'm using `strlen` to calculate the length of a string and if it exceeds x characters, `substr` it with a ellipses. The problem is, if there are special characters, the `strlen` function spits out an inaccurate number, causing ellipses to be added to strings that haven't exceeded x characters. What is a good method of calculating the length of a string in a way that works even with special characters involved, preferably counting a special character as a regular character so something like "W^a" counts as three characters.

Comment: Please provide some example of string you need to check length.

Answer (score 2):

If under `special characters` you mean something like öüóűőúéáí than you can try the mb_strlen method http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php with passing 'utf-8' as a second parameter.